# How to style KML?

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I have added drag and drop to my map, based on https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/drag-and-drop.html. Styling works for f.i. gpx but fails for kml.

Whatever I try, I can't get the kml features styled the way I want. Kml files with a style included are shown using that style but I cannot replace the style with my style. Kml with points but without a style are shown using a terrible old Google style push pin.

```
    var styleFunction = function (feature, resolution) {
  console.log("in styleFunction()");
  var featureStyleFunction = feature.getStyleFunction();
  if (featureStyleFunction) {
    return featureStyleFunction.call(feature, resolution);
  } else {
    return defaultStyle[feature.getGeometry().getType()];
  }
};

var dragAndDropInteraction = new ol.interaction.DragAndDrop({
  formatConstructors: [
    ol.format.GeoJSON,
    ol.format.TopoJSON,
    ol.format.EsriJSON,
    ol.format.IGC,
    ol.format.GPX,
    ol.format.KML
  ]
});

map.addInteraction(dragAndDropInteraction);

dragAndDropInteraction.on('addfeatures', function (event) {
  console.log("in dragAndDropInteraction");
  const ext = event.file.name.split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
  console.log("  ext: " + ext);
  let vectorSource;
  let layer;
  switch (ext) {
    case 'gpx':
      vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
        features: event.features,
        format: new ol.format.GPX(),
        // readExtensions: 
      });
      break;
    case 'kml':
      vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
        features: event.features,
        format: new ol.format.KML({
          extractStyles: false,
          // showPointNames: false,
          // extractAttributes: true,
          // writeStyles: false
        }),
      });
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
  if (vectorSource) {
    map.addLayer(new ol.layer.Vector({
      source: vectorSource,
      style: styleFunction 
    }));
    map.getView().fit(vectorSource.getExtent());
  }
```

An example at [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Albert8017/2upevLgo/)

Thanks.